# Is it acceptable to use a hidden window in a server application on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I'm thinking about using [WSAAsyncSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741540%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in a server. But then I need a window to receive the message.

Is such a (hidden) window acceptable in a server app without a GUI? Can it lead to unexpected problems?

Comment: You could also consider moving your socket code to a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a hidden window is probably ok, or even better, use a [message only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only).

Is there any reason why you can't use [WSAEventSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and events instead?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about WSAEventSelect. Looks like the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

It *can* lead to problems, if you react to certain messages that can be broadcast (or sent directly with malicious intent). The proper way is to ignore them under such circumstances. Obviously a "rogue" process could send stuff to your window in its hidden state. The reason I say it can be a problem, because this is exactly what allowed for [shatter attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attacks) some years back. Higher privilege processes accepting messages from lower privilege processes.

In newer Windows versions the *integrity levels* and the [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202.aspx) function (et. al.) help to lower risks.

Personally I think you didn't give enough data to make an assessment of the situation with the certainty that you probably expect. I just want to make sure you understand that, yes, even for a hidden window there are risks involved and that you should take precautions to mitigate them. But I agree with Anders, why not use `WSAEventSelect` and drop the window?